# how to quickly identify phpunit errors / failures when gnu parallel is used on travis ci

Tags: phpunit, travis-ci, gnu-parallel

GNU Parallel can be used to greatly speed up PHPUnit tests on Travis CI like so:

```
find tests -type f -name "*Test.php" | \
  parallel --gnu --keep-order \
    "echo '== {} =='; \"$(dirname "$0")/../vendor/bin/phpunit\" --verbose {};"
```

The problem with speeding unit tests up like this is that when a unit test does fail it can sometimes be quite difficult to figure out which exact one failed. Especially if there are like 1,000+ individual tests.

Like without Parallels all the failure are lumped together at after the `...E...S...` stuff. But with Parallels it's all over the place. You'll have a `...` string and then the details of those three tests, then a `E...` string and the error (E) will be explained after that, etc.

Usually I'm able to find failures pretty quickly by looking for "Failure" or "Error" but sometimes there are tests where I just can't see why it's failing at all.

My question is...  is there an easy way to search the Travis CI output, when GNU Parallels is in use, to find errors and failures and whatever else might cause a Travis CI container to fail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that can help.

`--tag` will make it easy to see which file we are talking about.

By design GNU Parallel does not mix stderr and stdout.

But if the error is given on stderr and the rest on stdout, then it can be a good idea to mix the two:

```
"... phpunit --verbose {} 2>&1"
```

This way the stderr output will be closer to the stdout output.